# how to prevent outlook from breaking div size? (newsletter)

Tags: html, css, outlook, mailchimp, newsletter

i'm making a newsletter in mailchimp, and I'm having this problem with outlook, it's keep messing with my two columns, like shown on this picture:

[image: example1]

Here's the code for this part:

```
<table class="bodyContent" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" mc:repeatable="fdvpeat" mc:variant="Two column block - With images">
        <tr>
                                <td width="50%" align="left" valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse !important;">
                                    <div class="leftcolumn" style="padding: 0 10px 0 0;" mc:edit="leftcolumn">
                                        <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/32275150c7338039c53c72339/images/ea2761e8-68e4-4ebc-b5ec-e0fe6227cfce.jpg" alt="" border="0" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;border: 0;outline: none;text-decoration: none;display: block;margin-top: 10px;margin-bottom: 11px;width: 270px !important;min-width: 270px !important;max-width: 270px !important;height: 150px !important;min-height: 150px !important;max-height: 150px !important;" class="halfsize">
                                        <div>
                                            <h3 style="padding: 0;margin-top: 10px;margin-right: 0;margin-bottom: 0;margin-left: 0;color: #222222 !important;display: block;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, Helmet, Freesans, sans-serif;font-size: 16px;font-weight: bold;line-height: 131%;text-align: left;">Planet express</h3>

                                            <p style="padding: 0;margin-top: 10px;margin-right: 0;margin-bottom: 11px;margin-left: 0;color: #222222 !important;display: block;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, Helmet, Freesans, sans-serif;font-size: 14px;font-weight: normal;line-height: 150%;text-align: left;">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td width="50%" align="left" valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse !important;">
                                    <div class="rightcolumn" style="padding: 0 0 0 10px;" mc:edit="rightcolumn">
                                        <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/32275150c7338039c53c72339/images/96456a30-0d44-4cc6-b689-bd92b97ea6d0.jpg" alt="" border="0" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;border: 0;outline: none;text-decoration: none;display: block;margin-top: 10px;margin-bottom: 11px;width: 270px !important;min-width: 270px !important;max-width: 270px !important;height: 150px !important;min-height: 150px !important;max-height: 150px !important;" class="halfsize">
                                        <div>
                                            <h3 style="padding: 0;margin-top: 10px;margin-right: 0;margin-bottom: 0;margin-left: 0;color: #222222 !important;display: block;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, Helmet, Freesans, sans-serif;font-size: 16px;font-weight: bold;line-height: 131%;text-align: left;">Good news everyone!</h3>

                                            <p style="padding: 0;margin-top: 10px;margin-right: 0;margin-bottom: 11px;margin-left: 0;color: #222222 !important;display: block;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, Helmet, Freesans, sans-serif;font-size: 14px;font-weight: normal;line-height: 150%;text-align: left;">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
    </table>
```

It's also messing with centering the TOS:

[image: Example here]

And here's the example for this part:

```
<tr>
                    <td align="left" valign="top" id="templateTOC" style="background-color: #969696;border-collapse: collapse !important;">
                        <div id="top"></div>
                        <h2 style="padding: 0;margin-top: 10px;margin-right: 0;margin-bottom: 11px;margin-left: 0;color: #ffffff !important;display: block;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, Helmet, Freesans, sans-serif;font-size: 21px;font-weight: bold;line-height: 129%;text-align: left;">In this issue...</h2>
                        <ul id="mctoc">
                            <li><a href="#mctoc1">Featured Research: Online Representation of the Arab World</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#mctoc2">Policy Impact</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#mctoc3">Staff News</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#mctoc4">Teaching News</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#mctoc5">Recent News</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#mctoc6">Forthcoming Events</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse !important;">
```

Thank you all for your help. I tried my things, but as a beginner, I just can't get it right somehow.

Answer (score 0):

For the two column, the issue is Outlook ignores padding on DIVs.  Moving the DIV padding to the TD and reducing it from 50% to 49% (this is something I do as some email clients like to add margins, etc in automatically and potentially can break the design. With the 2% buffer, it negates this) solved the problem in all outlooks I could see.

```
<table class="bodyContent" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" mc:repeatable="fdvpeat" mc:variant="Two column block - With images">
        <tr>
                                <td width="49%" align="left" valign="top" style="padding: 0 10px 0 0; border-collapse: collapse !important;">
                                    <div class="leftcolumn" mc:edit="leftcolumn">
                                        <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/32275150c7338039c53c72339/images/ea2761e8-68e4-4ebc-b5ec-e0fe6227cfce.jpg" alt="" border="0" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;border: 0;outline: none;text-decoration: none;display: block;margin-top: 10px;margin-bottom: 11px;width: 270px !important;min-width: 270px !important;max-width: 270px !important;height: 150px !important;min-height: 150px !important;max-height: 150px !important;" class="halfsize">
                                        <div>
                                            <h3 style="padding: 0;margin-top: 10px;margin-right: 0;margin-bottom: 0;margin-left: 0;color: #222222 !important;display: block;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, Helmet, Freesans, sans-serif;font-size: 16px;font-weight: bold;line-height: 131%;text-align: left;">Planet express</h3>

                                            <p style="padding: 0;margin-top: 10px;margin-right: 0;margin-bottom: 11px;margin-left: 0;color: #222222 !important;display: block;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, Helmet, Freesans, sans-serif;font-size: 14px;font-weight: normal;line-height: 150%;text-align: left;">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td width="49%" align="left" valign="top" style="padding: 0 0 0 10px; border-collapse: collapse !important;">
                                    <div class="rightcolumn" mc:edit="rightcolumn">
                                        <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/32275150c7338039c53c72339/images/96456a30-0d44-4cc6-b689-bd92b97ea6d0.jpg" alt="" border="0" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;border: 0;outline: none;text-decoration: none;display: block;margin-top: 10px;margin-bottom: 11px;width: 270px !important;min-width: 270px !important;max-width: 270px !important;height: 150px !important;min-height: 150px !important;max-height: 150px !important;" class="halfsize">
                                        <div>
                                            <h3 style="padding: 0;margin-top: 10px;margin-right: 0;margin-bottom: 0;margin-left: 0;color: #222222 !important;display: block;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, Helmet, Freesans, sans-serif;font-size: 16px;font-weight: bold;line-height: 131%;text-align: left;">Good news everyone!</h3>

                                            <p style="padding: 0;margin-top: 10px;margin-right: 0;margin-bottom: 11px;margin-left: 0;color: #222222 !important;display: block;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, Helmet, Freesans, sans-serif;font-size: 14px;font-weight: normal;line-height: 150%;text-align: left;">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
    </table>
```

For the TOC - I feel that there is some styling in a stylesheet that we are not seeing, if you can provide that it will help. My guess though is that the LI or UL elements have margins or paddings assigned to them in the stylesheet and Outlook does not like that, so it makes the bullets go crazy.